# Contact form 7 attachments not sending

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am having intermittent problems with contact form 7 - it sometimes sends and sometimes does not. The attachments seem to be the problem.

The form is routed via gmail SMTP.

I can submit one minute get an error and then send again 30 seconds later with success.

The error I am getting is the general - "Sender's message was failed to send"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error in the mail server log?

Comment: it is sending via gmail - so it would not appear in the apache mail logs?

Comment: It does - your emails are sent to smtp server through a MTA (Mail Transport Agent) in the better case, which will return a DSN if it fails. An other setup could be that the mail is sent through postfix, qmail etc to gmail, which will appear too in apache logs (or specific service logs). It depends how you set up your SMTP on your server, but in any case you will have DSN which will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it comes from the plugin contact form 7, I can't put my finger on it but it surely comes from the communication between your SMTP server and your Form.

because Contact Form 7 is only a plugin, not the server, it can be blocked from time to time by the server, so they inform you by that message.

I can't help you much but it's surely the server.

Comment: you mean the webserver or the mailserver?

Comment: the mailserver because Contact form 7 will only put this message if he had a conflict with the mail server, rejected, timeout or whatever.

Comment: It is routed via a  google apps account though so it should be solid. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: what I could recommend you is try it with the webserver SMTP and compare. if it continues then its Contact Form's issue.